# Change the status from statusbar in a model from wizards button Odoo

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo, statusbar, wizard

I need some help with the Odoo module.

I have a model that has a statusbar in its form, also I have some buttons on form to change statuses.
I've created a wizard, it has submit button, I want to add action on it to close the wizards window and change the statusbar's status on form.

Answer (score 0):

To close the wizard window, return this code on the button function inside wizard:

```
return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

To update the form behind the wizard, you can get Id of the record like this:

```
self.env.context.get('active_id')
```

After you get the Id, you can write() it.